# How to Guide Users to Add Widgets?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an app which is mainly two things: a widget that can be added to the hone screen, and a how-to-add-widget activity made out of images.

As I noticed, there are different ways to add widgets to the home screen depending on the device/android version. So, my activity's guided images will be different according to the device.

- Do you have suggestions in how I can display the right how-to in the right device?
- Is there a  programmatic way to open device's widgets list to the user?

Thanks.